# Many-to-Many Relationship With Same Table (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails app that has a "products" model. I want to be able to relate products to each other. Example: product 1 related to product 2, product 3, and vice versa. How would I accomplish this in Rails? I was thinking a join table, but since I'm using the same table as the point-of-relationship I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 3):

Untested and from memory, I think you'd want something like this:

```
class ProductLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_product, :class_name => 'Product'
  belongs_to :child_product, :class_name => 'Product'
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_links, :class_name => 'ProductLink', :foreign_key => :parent_product_id
  has_many :child_links, :class_name => 'ProductLink', :foreign_key => :child_product_id
end
```

ProductLink (or whatever you'd choose to call it) would then be able to contain one or more additional fields that describe the relationship.

You may be able to make it work with [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org), although I guess this would require a "products_products" table, which might be a little stressful.

Comment: From memory also, but wouldn't you use has_many :parent_products, :through 'ProductLink' and has_many :child_products, :through 'ProductLink'?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `acts_as_follower` gem. http://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/tree/master. It is pretty flexible in terms of following relationships and provides a generic following semantics.

Really simple, and works very well. Just use it to say product 1 follows product 2/3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need a join table. It needs two fields, both of which are foreign keys back to the products table.

So something like ProductRelation table with FirstProduct and SecondProduct fields (there probably is better names for those fields) then you know that FirstProduct is related to SecondProduct... then your queries for related products would be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Acts_as_nested-plugin!

[https://github.com/bbommarito/acts_as_nested_set](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set/tree/master)

Maybe also Ryan Bates screencasts helps you:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: I believe the correct URL above should be: 
http://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set

Comment: No, it should be https://github.com/bbommarito/acts_as_nested_set, corrected my post

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer the most useful:
[Ruby On Rails - many to many between the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098441/ruby-on-rails-many-to-many-between-the-same-table)

From this, I successfully implemented a bi-directional many-to-many association of a model to itself. In your case, it will be as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...

   has_many :parent_product_map, class_name: 'ProductMap', foreign_key: 'child_product_id'
   has_many :parent_products, through: :parent_product_map, source: :parent_product, class_name: 'Product'
   has_many :child_product_map, class_name: 'ProductMap', foreign_key: 'parent_product_id'
   has_many :child_products, through: :child_product_map, source: :child_product, class_name: 'Product'
   ...
end

class ProductMap < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :child_product_id, :id, :parent_product_id
   belongs_to :child_product, foreign_key: 'child_product_id', class_name: 'Product'
   belongs_to :parent_product, foreign_key: 'parent_product_id', class_name: 'Product'
end

class CreateProductMap < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :product_maps do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.timestamps
      t.integer :child_product_id
      t.integer :parent_product_id
    end
 end
```